# Переход с WindowsMediaPlayer на новую форму

Tags: c#

Как сделать так, чтобы после того , как видео закончится открылась новая форма?

Comment: Ну по сути да. WinForm: Как только видео заканчивается - windows media player закрывается и открывается новая форма. У wmp есть какое то похожие событие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам подойдет, то попробуйте пример отсюда: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx
В примере указано как вы можете работать с WindowsMediaPlayer через using WMPLib;
Если не найдет библиотеку, попробуйте найти ее по пути: \windows\system32\wmp.dll

На всякий случай код:

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player;

private void PlayFile(String url)
{
    Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    Player.PlayStateChange += 
        new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange);
    Player.MediaError += 
        new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MediaErrorEventHandler(Player_MediaError);
    Player.URL = url;
    Player.controls.play();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO  Insert a valid path in the line below.
    PlayFile(@"c:\myaudio.wma");
}

private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

private void Player_MediaError(object pMediaObject)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot play media file.");
    this.Close();
}
```

А внутри `Player_PlayStateChange` укажите какую форму в вашем приложении загрузить. Если вам нужно, чтобы при старте приложения не было видно формы, а только использовался плеер, скройте стартовую форму.

Comment: А где будет воспроизводиться моё видео? мне нужно добавить windowsmediaplayer?

Comment: Компонент для отображения? Да. Добавите его на форму и в нем будет отображаться видео, например. Можете глянуть видео с примером: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlIZQed46Jw